# Protection level issues when accessing a struct within an extension

Tags: swift, file-permissions, swift3, access-control, swift-extensions

I am attempting to implement the following library into my project:

https://github.com/knutigro/COBezierTableView

To use this, the following properties can be given custom values:

```
public extension UIView {

  public struct BezierPoints {

      static var p1 = CGPoint.zero
      static var p2 = CGPoint.zero
      static var p3 = CGPoint.zero
      static var p4 = CGPoint.zero
  }
}
```

In my MainVC this is configured as follows:

```
UIView.BezierPoints.p1 = CGPoint(...
UIView.BezierPoints.p2 = CGPoint(...
UIView.BezierPoints.p3 = CGPoint(...
UIView.BezierPoints.p4 = CGPoint(...
```

In the Swift 2.3 demo project there are no errors. In a Swift 3 project I am receiving the error:

**"p1 is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level."**

Can someone please shed some light on the issue here, I'm guessing Swift 3 has some new behind the scenes permissions taking over that need to be overridden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, the extension you are mentioning is not in the same target as your MainVC?

Because `p1` etc. don't have a protection level assigned (and the `struct` is not `private`), they are automatically `internal`. That means, that you can only access these properties within the same target.

But that was also the case in earlier versions of Swift. I don't know, why your code ever worked.

Comment: Oh of course! It hadn't occurred to me that the demo project didn't have the same targets. Changing the properties to public resolved this issue and I also found this useful resource https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/22/3-nuances-of-swift-extensions/